# html5 mp4 video slow loading in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

I want to show embedded video in my Angular app. The problem I am facing is that it is taking too long to load in Google Chrome (It takes around 5-10s), whereas it loads instantaneously in firefox. The format of the video is mp4, and I searched and found few issues related to Chrome and mp4 videos not working but my problem is slow loading.

My code is,

```html
   <video
    *ngIf="!isDialogOpen"
    class="videoURL"
    controls
    autoplay
    loop
    [muted]="true"
    [src]="mpVideoUrl"
   ></video>
```

Can this issue be related to the format/codec of the video? I would prefer a solution where I don't have to change it.

Answer (score 2):

all browsers have different buffering rules: depending on the speed of the network, and size of the video.  what is the bitrate/ size of the video you are attempting to play?

You can check this with https://ffprobe.a.video (just enter the URL of the video you're having issues with).